# Jesus had to move back in with his dad at age 33

Tags: meaning-in-context, jokes

> ***Jesus had to move back in with his dad at age 33***

I read this meme on facebook. What does it mean?

Comment: But his father's house had many rooms.

Comment: @TRomano So, not only did he move back home, he started preparing a bunch of rooms for his friends so they could move in too :) A very patient a loving father indeed.

Comment: I've have heard he had a posse.

Answer (score 15):

Jesus died when he was 33 years of age according to this meme.  As Jesus(from a Christian point-of-view) is the son of God, when he died, he went back to heaven to be reunited with his Father.

It's poking a bit of fun at Christianity by saying that Jesus couldn't make it on his own in the world and had to move back in with his parents to be supported.  Of course, this involves dying so there is a bit of morbid humor involved as well.

Comment: I don't think it's poking fun at Christianity. I think it's intended to be a lighthearted quip about 30-something people who end up [moving back in with their parents](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-deal-with-the-frustration-of-moving-back-in-with-1719610305) after falling on hard times. And the meme isn't saying he died on his 33rd birthday, but at the age of 33.

Comment: Good point about his age, but I read the joke as I posted it.  This is why these sorts of things are so fun.  So many ways to interpret.  Either way, it is all in fun, which can be difficult to do when religion becomes involved :)

Comment: Also, I think it is sort of related to the "What would Jesus do?" motto that turned into a meme. Because people might be unfairly critical of adults that are forced to move back in with their parents, and the "What would Jesus do?" motto is seen as self-righteous, pointing out that Jesus moved back in with his father when he was 33 is a clever way of tweaking the nose of people who might be a bit [sanctimonious](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sanctimonious?q=sanctimonious "giving the impression that you feel you are better and more moral than other people").

Comment: Well...no job, no girlfriend, his best friend betrayed him, no money. Of course he had to move back in.

Comment: @sumelic Yes, but let's please save that sort of debate for other SE sites where it would be more appropriate!